# Remove View in ViewGroup

Tags: java, android

I got some problems using ViewGroup and a automatically generated ViewPager.
I want to add a View and remove a view but everytime I am trying it I get the error:

```
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3524)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at de.tecfriends.vbtsplash2013.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment.Teilnehmer(MainActivity.java:219)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at de.tecfriends.vbtsplash2013.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment$1.onTaskCompleted(MainActivity.java:148)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at de.tecfriends.vbtsplash2013.BackgroundDownload.doInBackground(BackgroundDownload.java:38)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at de.tecfriends.vbtsplash2013.BackgroundDownload.doInBackground(BackgroundDownload.java:1)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    01-20 14:05:40.028: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     ... 4 more
```

In the Class `onCreateView` i set a public ViewGroup named `vGroup`. 
At the end of all data processing i try to `vGroup.removeView(vGroup.findViewById(1));` and `vGroup.addView(modeList);` but i get the error above.

How can I reach the `original Thread` where I can add and remove Views to this `ViewGroup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` means that you are trying to access UI elements from the background thread, which is the non-UI thread.

`vGroup.removeView()` should only be called from `onPreExecute()` or `onPostExecute()`, as these two functions run on the UI thread.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            .... // runs on background / non-UI thread
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
            ... // runs on UI thread            
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
            ... // runs on UI thread      
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      }
}
```

[Documentation of AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: So, i can't change the View after it is created? And how can i change to UI Thread?

Comment: You definitely can! But only from the preExecute and postExecute functions.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to reach these functions?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `vGroup.removeView()` from a background thread. To alter the UI you should/must always use the `UI Thread`.

**EDIT:** create a `Handler` on the `UIThread` and use `mHandler.post(new Runnable());`

Comment: Are you sure that i am in background Thread? I am calling the function from a BackgroundThread's `onTaskCompleted` function. Just tried, i dont have the function runOnUiThread in this Function available.

Comment: How can i reach the Ui Thread? runOnUiThread seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

next to use `vGroup.removeView()` you need to call `vGroup.refreshDrawableState()`

Comment: Are you saying that before using removeView, you must first use refreshDrawableState?